# How to remove this NullReferenceException in Unity

Tags: unity

```
NullReferenceException: (null)
 UnityEditor.SerializedObject..ctor (UnityEngine.Object[] objs) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/812c4f5049264fad/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/SerializedPropertyBindings.cs:39)
 UnityEditor.AssetImporterInspector.GetSerializedObjectInternal () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/812c4f5049264fad/Editor/Mono/ImportSettings/AssetImporterInspector.cs:52)
 UnityEditor.Editor.get_serializedObject () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/812c4f5049264fad/Editor/MonoGenerated/Editor/EditorBindings.cs:71)
 UnityEditor.ModelImporterClipEditor.OnEnable () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/812c4f5049264fad/Editor/Mono/ImportSettings/ModelImporterClipEditor.cs:89)
```

I am getting this error, even though i dont have cs files in project.

PROBLEM FIXED - Tried reinstalling Unity at different location and project is working with any error like this. Still puzzled why this issue happened, what i should not suppose to do.
Thank you all.

Comment: When do you get this exception ? When running your game or when opening a scene from it in Editor ?

Comment: I am getting this error without building. In Editor. Not able to build my project. I amusing Unity4.6.7.

Comment: One of your asset seems corrupted, seems like a model or a clip is causing the crash. Only thing I can propose to you is to try to remove assets one by one, each time saving & reopening the scene until the exception does not occur anymore, then you'll know which asset(s) have issues.

Comment: Ok i am trying to resolve.

Comment: I backed up my Assets folder. With empty project there is no error. When I put back Assets folder content. Unity Editor is crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting Unity IDE once.

Comment: Tried restarting but unity project is crashing without any error. should i reinstall unity?

Comment: Don't know what is the issue, try re-install and check please.

Comment: Trying reinstalling